# Guidelines to document php files with phpdoc2

Tags: php, document, phpdoc

Starting documenting my project, using phpdoc2 for the first time, I've come upon a few questions. I did read the guides on phpdoc.org.

Is there a guideline of what to document when using phpdoc2?
Do I have to document all variables or just the variables in a certain scope/visability.

As I understand it now, you document each:

- file
- class
- function

But even then... How far do you go using the tags?

Comment: Remember that you're documenting as much for yourself (or others that might need to change your code) in six months time when your memory isn't as fresh; so you document to as much level as is necessary for that

Answer (score 0):

The documentation should cover all what is most important. If it is possible, you could even give examples, external links and so on. I use doxygen software and find it very good, and this has these features.

The php.net manual is quite good. It covers every function, class, method, but also requirements, introduction and so on.

For me the worst problem is that I document every single detail and in some moment I say "I'm tired of this" and stop documenting or making comments at the most important parts. "I will remember".

It is always easier after a month or a year to delete something that is too long or redundant than to fill what is missing.

Find your point.